# How to download mobile version of a website using Scrapy

Tags: mobile, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to understand how to download the mobile version of a website using Scrapy (Google for example).

I don't know how to emulate those requests as I don't have a debugger in my phone. How could I do it using Scrapy or how could I debug mobile requests using my desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can totally use your desktop to emulate mobile behavior. Use Chrome's Developer  Tools and click the `Toogle device toolbar` button:

[image]

That way you can check which requests are being used for mobile version.

Now normally, this is specified by the `User-Agent` header, so just a mobile one, that could be for example changing the `USER_AGENT` in settings:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1'
```